# Make [trait] a synonym of [traits]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

These tags refer to the same concept :

[traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traits)

> In computer programming, a trait is a collection of methods, used as a "simple conceptual model for structuring object oriented programs"

[trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trait)

> A scala trait is roughly the equivalent of an interface in Java. It can be extended as it it were a class, and can contain concrete and abstract methods as well as variables.

Even if the [trait] tag description specifies **scala**, many questions with this tag are bound to other languages (rust, PHP, ...), which shows the confusion.

Since [traits] description is more generic and this tag has more questions tagged, I suggest to make [trait] a synonym of [traits]

Comment: And anything tagged [trait] intending the Scala meaning will also be tagged [scala], so no loss there, though I guess we could create [scala-trait].  (Can you follow only [scala][trait] together rather than individually?  Does anyone want to follow [scala-trait]?)

Comment: Agreed; I just ran into this myself. However, I think it should go the other way; [tag:trait] should be the primary with [tag:traits] as a synonym. See, e.g., [tag:class].